# Does bootstrap 4 have a built in horizontal divider?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Does bootstrap 4 have a built in horizontal divider? I can do this,

```
<style type="text/css">
.h-divider{
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 height:1px;
 width:100%;
 border-top:1px solid gray;
}
</style>
```

But I want to use the built in bootstrap css, I can't find it anywhere in the docs, maybe I'm missing it.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

HTML already has a built-in horizontal divider called `<hr/>` (short for "horizontal rule"). Bootstrap styles it [like this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L416-L421):

```
hr {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<p>
   Some text
   <hr/>
   More text
</p>
```

Comment: sometimes you need to add a class="w-100" or the <hr> will show as a dot.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/

Comment: Tested in Bootstrap 4, `border border-primary` classes work on `hr`.

Comment: This example is a great example of the semantic use of the <hr> element! 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr

Comment: Strange, our Bootstrap 4 scss has hr height 0  but we're using an old version of AdminLTE. I'm not sure why they're biased against hr tags.

Answer (score 89):

**Bootstrap 4** define a CSS style for the HTML built-in horizontal divider `<hr />`, so just use it.

You can also customize margin with spacing utilities: `mt` for margin top, `mb` for margin bottom and `my` for margin top and bottom. The integer represent spacing `1` for small margin and `5` for huge margin. Here is an example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<hr class="mt-2 mb-3"/>
<!-- OR -->
<hr class="my-12"/>
<!-- It's like -->
<hr class="mt-3 mb-3"/>
```

I used to be using just a `div` with `border-top` like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="border-top my-3"></div>
```

but it's a *silly* method to make the work done, and you can have some issues. So just use `<hr />`.

Comment: <div class="border-top my-3"></div>
instead of span use div

Comment: Relative to the question this answer is correct but border-* shouldn't be used as a divider. Imagine you want to separate multiple rows. If you apply border-* to a row it will span from side to side of the parent container. If you apply border-* to individual column then they won't look good when stacked on mobile. The only option is to use <hr/> just like the accepted answer suggested.

Answer (score 60):

**For Bootstrap 4**

`<hr>` still works for a normal divider. However, if you want a divider with text in the middle:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"><hr></div>
    <div class="col-auto">OR</div>
    <div class="col"><hr></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18):

For dropdowns, yes:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: ```<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>``` this is makes the divider

Answer (score 12):

**For Bootstrap v4;**

for a thin line;

```
<div class="divider"></div>
```

for a medium thick line;

```
<div class="divider py-1 bg-dark"></div>
```

for a thick line;

```
<div class="divider py-1 bg-dark"><hr></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `mt` and `mb` spacing utilities to add extra margins to the `<hr>`, for example:

```
<hr class="mt-5 mb-5">
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Did you mean `<hr class="my-5" />`?

Answer (score 5):

Here are some custom utility classes:

```css
hr.dashed {
    border-top: 2px dashed #999;
}

hr.dotted {
    border-top: 2px dotted #999;
}

hr.solid {
    border-top: 2px solid #999;
}


hr.hr-text {
  position: relative;
    border: none;
    height: 1px;
    background: #999;
}

hr.hr-text::before {
    content: attr(data-content);
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    color: #999;
    border-radius: 30rem;
    padding: 0.2rem 2rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}



/*
*
* ==========================================
* FOR DEMO PURPOSES
* ==========================================
*
*/

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fff; 
    color: #333;
}
.text-uppercase {
  letter-spacing: .1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container py-5">
    <!-- For Demo Purpose -->
    <header class="py-5 text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Bootstrap Divider</h1>
        <p class="lead mb-0">Some divider variants using &lt;hr&gt; element.    </p>
    </header>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
            <div class="mb-4">
                <h6 class=" text-uppercase">Dashed</h6>
                <!-- Dashed divider -->
                <hr class="dashed">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                <h6 class=" text-uppercase">Dotted</h6>
                <!-- Dotted divider -->
                <hr class="dotted">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                <h6 class="text-uppercase">Solid</h6>
                <!-- Solid divider -->
                <hr class="solid">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                <h6 class=" text-uppercase">Text content</h6>
                <!-- Gradient divider -->
                <hr data-content="AND" class="hr-text">
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

in Bootstrap 5 you can do something like this:

```
<div class="py-2 my-1 text-center position-relative mx-2">
            <div class="position-absolute w-100 top-50 start-50 translate-middle" style="z-index: 2">
                <span class="d-inline-block bg-white px-2 text-muted">or</span>
            </div>
            <div class="position-absolute w-100 top-50 start-0 border-muted border-top"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown">
      Sample Button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
      <li>C</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is the sample code for the horizontal divider in bootstrap 4.  [Output looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgDUa.png)

class="dropdown-divider" used in bootstrap 4, while class="divider" used in bootstrap 3 for horizontal divider

Answer (score 2):

```html
   <div class="form-group col-12">
            <hr>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this example in my project:

html:

```
 <hr class="my-3 dividerClass"/>
```

css:

```
.dividerClass{
  border-top-color: #999
 }
```

Comment: also: <p style="border-top-width: thin; border-top-color: #999; border-top-style: solid;"></p>

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I did it in Express.js + Pug:

**CSS:**

```
.divider-text {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.divider-text span {
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.divider-text:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    top: 55%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**PUG code:**

```
p.divider-text
    span.bg-light OR
```

Which then compiles into this:

**HTML:**

```
<p class="divider-text"><span class="bg-light">OR</span></p>
```

**Visual Result:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

bootstrap 5.2

```
<div class="vr"></div>
```

Comment: This is not a horizontal divider. It is a vertical divider.