# Does bootstrap 5 have a built-in horizontal line?

Tags: bootstrap-5, horizontal-line

I'm looking for styled or colored horizontal lines, preferably with success, primary, warning classes.
A similar concept to [colored links.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/colored-links/)

I couldn't find this topic on Bootstrap's website.

I found a few working solutions referring to [Bootstrap v4.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64277965/7995811)

In my case:

`<div class="divider py-1 bg-success"></div>`

It works, but I guess it's not the best practice...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes it does.  Part of the Reboot, and is present in both `Bootstrap-reboot.css` & `Bootstrap.css`.  It defines the `<hr>` as:

```css
hr {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: currentColor;
  border: 0;
  opacity: 0.25;
}
```

Also, Bootstrap 5 has moved a lot of its UI control over to utility classes... that gives you a far richer control of your UI.  For example, if you wanted a "danger" / red colour `<hr>` you could use:

```html
<hr class="bg-danger border-2 border-top border-danger" />
```

Have a look at the Utility classes in [their docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/).

Comment: It seems I need to be more fluent with Sass to fully use utility classes. I thought I could find ready-to-use Bootstrap components.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-1 border-bottom"></div>
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

Using `hr` with [the spacers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/) helped me.  Example horizontal rule that has a bit of space on top and bottom:

```
    <hr class="mt-1 mb-1"/>
```

Comment: ``<hr class="my-1">`` ;)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use the `<hr>` tag using BootStrap5 is to use the border as stated above, but you have several options that give you more control over the `<hr>` tag. For instance this controls the thickness and color.

`<hr class="border-bottom border-3 border-dark">`

Comment: Tip: use backticks to avoid HTML tags turning into rendered code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="border-top">
  top bordered section
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**