# Why does Boostrap change my html layout and how to get the original format back?

Tags: html, bootstrap-accordion

```css
.block { display: inline-block; }
.row {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
hr {
  border-top: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
         <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="block">Lorem</div>
      <div class="block">Ipsum</div>
      <div class="block">Dolor</div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

For this example, if I remove the Boostrap reference, the 3 items will be displayed horizontally on one line at right top corner:

```
Lorem Ipsum Dolor
```

But the boostrap changed it to vertical display after I adding Boostrap library. How to get the 3 items back to be displayed horizontally, still at the right top corner?

The

---

tag was changed to the following by boostrap:

```
hr {
    margin: 1
rem
 0;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: currentColor;
    border: 0;
    opacity: .25;
}
```

How to use my own 'hr' defined in css file? I added my own 'hr' definition.

Comment: The framework override it. The best practice is to inspect those element and find what rules are applied on. Then override them with a custom style.

Comment: For this example, how to find what rules are applied on? I saw class='row' applied.

Comment: Can you make some fiddle codepan etc?

Comment: Use your Developer Tools in your browser to find out what it overriding it.

Comment: @A.Meshu, please see my updated complete example, and you can see the effect of removing boostrap.

Comment: @disinfor I can use Inspect to see the 'class='row', but don't know how to use developer tools to get the clue.

Comment: If you look in the CSS panel, you can see what styles are overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the classes `.block` and `.row`. Those are about as conventional as you can possibly get so bootstrap uses them as well. When you include bootstrap it overides your css. The easiest thing to do is to simply change your class names. Maybe prefix your custom classes with a prefix relating to you site. Ie if your site is `bla.com` use `bla-block` and `bla-row` that way you have a way lower chance of conflicting with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The framework set `.row` flex display. It also set `.block` with 100% width.
You can solve that like that:

```
.row { justify-content: flex-end;}
.block {width: auto!important;}
```

```css
.block { display: inline-block; }
.row {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
.row { justify-content: flex-end;}
.block {width: auto!important; padding-right:0!important}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="block">Lorem</div>
      <div class="block">Ipsum</div>
      <div class="block">Dolor</div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: There are too much space between the items. How to make it only one  white space?

Comment: add `padding-right: 0!important` - i updated the snippet. You really should work with the inspector - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector

Comment: In the inspector, how to know which overrider which?

Comment: So you right-click on the desired element, click on `inspect`, and you get on the left the dom tree and on the right the css that apply on it - and from where (the source ie bootstrap style, your file etc). My English not that good in order to continue... This is the reason i linked mdn (:

Comment: It also changed my 'hr' definition when I looked at it in the inspection. How to use my own hr?

Comment: @marlon why to use boots at all.. LOL (:

Comment: I want to use collapse and uncollapse to by default hide something. Is there another simple way to do it?

Comment: This example uses `jQuery`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849514/how-to-open-only-1-accordion-at-one-time/64850399#64850399 I can dig to find some other answers... (:

Comment: But can you please see how to fix the 'hr' display issue? I have spent some time to look at Boostrap. Also, the example you gave uses Boostrap.

Comment: Actually you got thread that explain this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66110604/does-bootstrap-5-have-a-built-in-horizontal-line

Comment: Which means I should use 'hr  class='xxx'  defined by Boostrap, not my own ?

Comment: Or like your initial question - override it style with `!important`

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is pretty much a HTML-everything-done-ready-to-go template. By editing standard Bootstrap features like `Row` and `Container` we probably do more to confuse Bootstrap and then scratch our heads as to why the site doesn't look right. I do think that when using Bootstrap there is some brain training involved with using it's own settings in our HTML instead of creating more lines of unrequired code in CSS. Eg a lot of people add Margins or Padding via CSS but this is just 3 characters long in Bootstrap HTML. `class="p-5"` is padding x5 for example.